# What is dynamic method dispatch and how does it relate to inheritance?

Tags: java

What is meant by *dynamic dispatch* in Java, and why do we need it in the context of inheritance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **What is meant by *dynamic dispatch* in Java […]?**

Think of "dispatch" as "determining which method to call".

The "dynamic" part simply says that it is determined at runtime. That is, which method is to be called is determined at runtime.

> **why do we need it in the context of inheritance**

Without inheritance / polymorphism we wouldn't need this. The type of an expression would be decidable at compile time, and which method that would have been called at runtime would be known when compiling the program.

With inheritance / polymorphism we don't know the concrete runtime type of an expression, thus which method to be called must be "dynamically" determined during runtime.

Without dynamic dispatch, virtual methods wouldn't make sense, which is central for abstraction and encapsulation.

Recommended reading: [Wikipedia article on Dynamic Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)

Comment: Can you please share some example to explain this point `With inheritance / polymorphism we don't know the concrete runtime type of an expression, thus which method to be called must be "dynamically" determined during runtime.`

Comment: It's quite simple: If you weren't allowed to do `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();` but _had_ to do `ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();` you wouldn't need dynamic dispatch, because the type of `l` would necessarily be `ArrayList` in runtime (that is it couldn't be any other `List`). This would make dynamic dispatch meaningless since the compiler could just hard wire a call to `l.add(...)` to the `ArrayList.add` method (as opposed to wiring it to `List.add` and dispatch it to `ArrayList.add` or `LinkedList.add` dynamically).

Comment: got it now. And as I know there are 2 forms of Dynamic dispatch. `single` and `double/multiple` dispatch.  Could you please share some light on those too. Preferably with an small example.

Comment: Single dispatch: You base your choice of method on a single input, for example the object type. Multiple dispatch: You base your choice on multiple input, for example the object type, and the argument types. In Java you can call different methods depending on which type of arguments you provide, (method overloading) but this mechanism works entirely in compile time. So for multiple dispatch, imagine this was decided in runtime: `Object o = "hello"; m(o);` and `Object o = new Integer(5); m(o);` could call different methods.

Comment: Ah, in java the two method calls will invoke the same method `m`, since both `o`s are `Object` types. If it supported `multiple dispatch` it should call two different methods. Thank you very much for clearing that piece.  But anyway Java is not supporting multiple dispatch. Any idea why.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but possible explanations are: Efficiency. Simplicity. Same semantics as virtual methods in C++.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for explaining so much. But I have few other questions regarding `Dynamic Dispatch` hope you don't mind (I have few others also it's better to ask a SO question later). Is it different from `Late Binding` ? Coz one other answer in this page state that `...dynamic dispatch (also called late binding) is ...` . Basically are `dispatching` and `Binding` the same ?

Comment: Reading [this](https://lukasatkinson.de/2016/dynamic-vs-static-dispatch/) it seems to me as if late binding is more or less the same thing as dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Hmm Anyway I asked a question.  If you have please look into this and provide some thoughts :) Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 13):

Other Answers discus the theory, this is an example to show why dynamic dispatch (also called late binding) is needed.

Assume you have an Class 'Rectangle`.

```
public class Rectangle{
  public void draw() {
     System.out.println("___\n| |\n---");
     //does it look nice?
  }
}
```

And you have a subclass with rounded corners

```
public class RoundedRectangle extends Rectangle {
  @Override
  public void draw() {
     System.out.println("assume it is a rectangle with rounded corners");
  }
}
```

Now assume you have a method getting with an Parameter of Type Rectangle, which is used in the method to invoke the draw method

```
public class Demo() {
...
  public demonstration(Rectangle rect) {
    rect.draw();
  }
...
}
```

It the argument of this method is of class Rectangle then it will draw

```
___
| |
---
```

But when the argument is of type RoundedRectangle, then we expect:

```
assume it is a rectangle with rounded corners
```

And this is where late binding is needed for: When the code compiles, it is not clear which method needs to be invoked by
rect.draw();
I could be Rectangle.draw(), RoundedRectangle.draw(), or the draw method of any other yet not implemented subclass of Rectangle.

Summary (from the view of an developer):

So late binding means: invoke the method of given signature (Method name, and argument list) for an instance where is only known that it is of an specific class or subclass - but it is not known which class it is exactly. And when a method is overriden, then ivoke the overriding method.

So there is no Polymorphism vs. Late Binding -- It is you need Late Binding when you have Polymorphism. In Java and in C++ (and i belive, in every other Object Oriented language too)

Comment: @Ralph This answer is great !!!  Could you please share some light on the `single dispatch` and `double/multiple dispatch` with examples.

Answer (score 1):

> What is dynamic method dispatch in case of java

Same as it is in any other language. Despatching dynamically to a method chosen on the basis of the type of the object the method is invoked on.

> and why do we need that in case of inheritance(what is the need of DMD)

That's the only time you *do* need it. If you don't have inheritance there is nothing to be dynamic about.

> Which one is better Polymorphism in C++ or DMD in java.

The question is meaningless, as they aren't different. DMD is a mechanism for implementing one aspect of polymorphism.