# In which cases reference variable in Java should be used?

Tags: java, overriding

I understand the concept that in Java, a reference variable of super class can refer to object of its subclass. But I really don't understand why is it important in the following or any other cases:

```
class Figure {
    double dim1 , dim2;
    Figure(double a, double b){
        dim1 = a;
        dim2 = b;
    }
    double area(){
        System.out.println("Area undefined");
        return 0;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Figure{
    Rectangle(int a, int b){
        super(a,b);
    }
    double area(){
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle:");
        return dim1*dim2;
    }
}

class Triangle extends Figure{
    Triangle(int a, int b){
        super(a,b);
    }
    double area(){
        System.out.println("Area of triangle:");
        return dim1*dim2/2; 
    }
}

class CalArea{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Figure fig = new Figure(10,10);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,10);
        Triangle tri = new Triangle(10,15);

        Figure figref;      //Figure class reference
        figref = fig;
        System.out.println(figref.area());

        figref = rect;
        System.out.println(figref.area());

        figref = tri;
        System.out.println(figref.area());
    }
}
```

Here instead of referring variable **figref** of superclass **Figure** to every object of its subclasses **Rectangle** and **Triangle** , I could have just called the **area()** methods of each class with their respective objects.
Is it important so that we could implement **Dynamic Method Dispatch** ??

Please provide a much more real life example so I understand the importance of it and where it should be applied.

Comment: In the duplicate, this answer is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343661/180100 (in your example, imagine you want to DRY and have a method for `System.out.println(figref.area());`)

Comment: Instead of writing `System.out.println(figref.area())` three times, try writing a method to print the area, `static void printArea(Figure figref)` and calling the method three times.  `printArea` won't know which kind of figure it has.